# Данные об использовании Dyno hours в Heroku

Tags: heroku

Пришло письмо от Heroku, что одно, или несколько моих приложений использовали 80% Dyno часов...
Как узнать информацию, какое приложение сколько потребляет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете увидеть это в настройках учетной записи.

Нажмите на свой аватар в правом верхнем углу сайта и выберите **Account settings**, перейдите во вкладку **Billing**. Смотрите раздел **"Free Dyno Usage"**.

Прямая ссылка: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing